# how I can make stacked element scroll in flutter

Tags: flutter

I need to show the elements of the list view under each Other like its seem in the image

I tried to use some packages  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JlPn5.png)

tried to use some packages use stack Align  positioned and sliver still no result